# What is the meaning of the word 「から」 in this sentence?

Tags: translation, particle-から

Here is the sentence including the word.

> 丈少年をかこんでなごやかな子どもたちの写真をとらせてください。新聞に大きくのせます**から**。

I'm not sure if I can translate it as 'Then' like this:

> Please let me take a photograph of you kids surrounding the boy 'Joe'. **Then** it will be put in a newspaper with a large picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as meaning goes,

> 「丈少年をかこんでなごやかな子どもたちの写真をとらせてください。新聞に大きくのせます**から**。」

＝

> 「新聞に大きくのせます**から**、丈少年をかこんでなごやかな子どもたちの写真をとらせてください。」

The dictionary definitions of this 「から」 would be "because" or "as".

My own would be "so that (I will be able to) ~~", "so that (it will enable me to) ~~".

This 「から」 is often placed at the end of a sentence.